# Digit grouping in python hexadecimal number formatting

Tags: python, hex, python-3.4, number-formatting

Say I have a bunch of hexadecimal numbers that I’m printing in python, e,g, addresses for debugging purposes, and I want to be able to compare them visually. A great help for that would be to group digits similarly to how we use thousands separators for decimal numbers.

This is also the reason why when you hexdump something digits are grouped by 4, rather than unfathomly long strings of hexadecimal characters.

Unreadable: 47167689711616
Barely readable: 2ae61563e000
Half-readable: 47,167,689,711,616
Most-readable: 2ae6,1563,e000

I don't really care what the separator is, if the grouping is by 2, 3, or 4 digits. However, the option for grouping seems not to be working:

```
>>> '{:x}'.format(47167689711616)
'2ae61563e000'
>>> '{:,x}'.format(47167689711616)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Cannot specify ',' with 'x'.
```

The machine I’m using (and where I’m not admin) only has **python 3.4**.

Answer (score 7):

A new grouping option “**_**” has been [introduced in python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#grammar-token-grouping-option):

> The '_' option signals the use of an underscore for a thousands
>   separator for floating point presentation types and for integer
>   presentation type 'd'. For integer presentation types 'b', 'o', 'x',
>   and 'X', underscores will be inserted every 4 digits. For other
>   presentation types, specifying this option is an error.
>
> *Changed in version 3.6*: Added the '_' option (see also 
>   [PEP 515 -- Underscores in Numeric Literals](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0515/)).

Example:

```
>>> '{:_x}'.format(47167689711616)
'2ae6_1563_e000'
```

Of course this helps on an up-to-date machine, but not with python 3.4.

Comment: Note that the width specification also counts separators, so `f'{123456:09_x}'` will give you `0001_e240`.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using the grouper [recipe](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) from the itertools [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html).

```
>>> import itertools

>>> def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
...     args = [iter(iterable)] * n
...     return itertools.zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
... 
>>>

>>> n = 47167689711616
>>> fs = '{:x}'.format(n) 
>>> fs
'2ae61563e000'
>>> list(''.join(x) for x in grouper(fs, 4, '0'))
['2ae6', '1563', 'e000']
```

Or for string ooutput:

```
>>> ' '.join(''.join(x) for x in grouper(fs, 4, '0'))
'2ae6 1563 e000'
```

This will work on Python 3.4

Comment: This mostly works. You’re using `zip_longest` instead of `zip` to anticipate the case where the number of digits isn’t a multiple of `n` (and then fillvalue should be e.g. `''`. However this leaves any non-multiple of n groups in the right-most position instead of left. You can solve that by reversing the sequence twice (though it’s not very elegant?): `lambda num: ''.join(reversed('_'.join(''.join(x) for x in itertools.zip_longest(*([iter(reversed('{:x}'.format(num)))] * 4), fillvalue = ''))))`

Comment: @Cimbali, yes, `'0'` was a poor choice of fill value - I perhaps should have chosen something obviously non-numeric to make fills more obvious, then the OP could decide how to handle them, if their stream isn't an exact multiple of the group value.